# Another conjecture on sum $A+B=C$

Tags: nt.number-theory, computer-science, diophantine-equations

> Could You give your ideas, your comment, or a referen for a conjecture as follows:

Consider $A, B, C$ be three positive integers numbers. By [Fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) we write:

$A=a_1^{x_1}a_2^{x_2}...a_n^{x_n}$,

$B=b_1^{y_1}b_2^{y_2}...b_m^{y_m}$,

$C=c_1^{z_1}c_2^{z_2}...c_k^{z_k}$

Let $N=\min\{x_i, y_j, z_h \}$ where $1 \le i \le n,  1\ \le j \le m, 1\le h \le k$

> For a positive integer $N_0 > 3$, there exist only finitely many triples $(A, B, C)$ of coprime positive integers, with $A+B=C$, such that: $N \ge N_0$

**Edited:** I repalced $N_0 \ge 3$ by $N_0 > 3$

Comment: How does this differ from this question you asked on MSE? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2345108/another-conjecture-on-sum-ab-c

Comment: @YemonChoi Yes, In my ideas, the first time I must write the conjecture with above form. Original form I write that if $A+B=C$ then exist $x_i<3$, $y_j<3$ or  $z_h < 3$. But  for principles in my ideas, I should write the conjecture as above form. So I also changes one time in:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2345108/another-conjecture-on-sum-ab-c

Comment: You should look at Mazur's Questions about powers of numbers: http://www.ams.org/notices/200002/fea-mazur.pdf

Comment: I repalced $N_0 \ge 3$ by $N_0 >2$

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This conjecture is false, though only barely.

It should be true for $N_0 \geq 4$ by the ABC conjecture.
But for $N_0 = 3$ there are infinitely many counterexamples such as
$$
191114642^3 + 4309182809^3 = 7^4 \, 321817873^3.
$$
I obtained this by starting from the point 
$P_1 = (2:1:1)$ on the elliptic curve $x^3+y^3=7z^3$ 
(with origin $P_0 = (1:-1:0)$), and looking for a multiple 
$P_n = nP_1$ whose $z$-coordinate is divisible by $7$; such $n$ must exist because $7|z(P_n)$ **iff** $P_n$ reduces mod $7$ to $P_0$,
and here it turned out that $n=7$ was the first example.
Then any $n=7m$ works, so we get an infinite sequence of counterexamples.

The same construction works for any elliptic curve $x^3+y^3=Dz^3$
of positive rank.

P.S. I see that a simpler counterexample$$
271^3 + 3^5 146^3 = 919^3
$$
was given by **user459832** to 
[the parallel question
on Math Stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2345108/another-conjecture-on-sum-ab-c).  This corresponds to the third multiple of
the generator $(2:1:1)$ on $x^3+y^3=9z^3$; here the first case of $3|z$
is small enough that we can still comfortably exhibit the next one, 
$$
415280564497^3 + 676702467503^3 = 3^5 116223894220^3.
$$

Comment: Can You help me improving the conjecture?

Comment: Dear Dr. @NoamD.Elkies if $N_0 \ge 4$ the conjecture can easily prove by abc conjecture? Or can using this conjecture to prove the abc conjecture?

Comment: Your conjecture for $N_0 \geq 4$ is a special case of the ABC conjecture;
that's what I was getting at in the second sentence of my answer.
The ABC conjecture is much stronger, so I don't think that a proof of the $N_0 \geq 4$ part
of your conjecture could be used to prove the full ABC conjecture.
Still I don't think any techniques are known for solving even your
more modest conjecture for any value of $N_0$, however large
(except of course if Mochizuki's approach to the full ABC conjecture
turns out to work).

Comment: I repalced $N_0 \ge 3$ by $N_0 >2$

Comment: Dear @NoamD.Elkies Since your answer, and comment of  Yaakov Baruch. The conjecture here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/303141/is-the-conjecture-ab-c-following-correct true up to $10^{18}$. So we can state that: $h(A), h(B), h(C) \le 3$  there are infinity solution, and $h(A), h(B), h(C) >3$ there are no solution for equation $A+B=C$, $gcd(A,B)=1$